# SSIS OData Connection Manager Not Hooking Up With SharePoint

Tags: ssis, odata, sharepoint-online

I'm being forced to move away from a fileshare that was working perfectly to SharePoint. I've spent the past hour trying to create the needed connection string between SSIS and SharePoint but am getting the error below when Testing the Connection.  Has anybody else had this issue? Any idea on what I can do to fix it?

[image]